# How to set setInterval function to work with each separate element

Tags: javascript, html, css, settimeout, setinterval

thanks for your time reviewing this question.

I am trying to display each image separately after a short break but seems like setTimeout or setInterval is not a good tool here, however, I googled all the available instruments but apparently these two are the only available. I can't use them since they will stack the function calls and will display all the elements at once. So then, I need to clear the redundant elements that is not what I expect my function to do.

I have the following code:

```js
imagesToShow = document.getElementsByClassName("image-to-show");
let revealing;
console.log(imagesToShow);
for (const iterator of imagesToShow) {
  iterator.classList.add("isHidden");
}
const fadeIn = setTimeout(() => {
  for (const iterator of imagesToShow) {
    iterator.classList.remove("isHidden");
  }
}, 500);
```

```css
.isHidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Style/style.css" />
    <script src="./script/script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Banners</title>
    <style>
      .image-to-show {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
      }

      .images-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
      .button-wrapper {
        height: 300px;
        margin-top: 100px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }
      .slide-stop,
      .slide-start {
        outline: none;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin-right: 30px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="images-wrapper">
      <img src="./img/1.jpg" alt="image of game" class="image-to-show" />
      <img src="./img/2.jpg" alt="image of game" class="image-to-show" />
      <img src="./img/3.JPG" alt="image of game" class="image-to-show" />
      <img src="./img/4.png" alt="image of game" class="image-to-show" />
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
      <button class="slide-start">Start slideshow</button>
      <button class="slide-stop">Stop slideshow</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Could you please advise how to make sure it works with each element or maybe there is an alternative like "sleep" in C#. I need to display each and every element but it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: No, sorry, I did it, like that's how I tried to solve the problem. I tried to change the location of setInterval or put it inside of the function. The code that I included is the last version that still doesn't work. That's why I came with the question because I did whatever I could and still setInterval or setTimeout doesn't work due to it's nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your code is written, you are essentially waiting 500ms and then showing all the images at once.

You could set a timeout to show each image like so:

```js
for (const i in imagesToShow) {
  setTimeout(() => imagesToShow[i].classList.remove("isHidden"), i * 500);
}
```

The `i * 500` will show the first image after `0ms`, second one after `500ms`, third after `1000ms`, etc.

Comment: Do you know why it displays all the images at once? That's how I think. I have a loop that extracts the element from collection then it passes this element into a function that will wait for 500ms and then it will do the body of the function, then again, the loop extracts the second element and so on. Not sure why it doesn't work this way. What actually happens. It accepts the first element, saves it in the memory, then the second one and so on and then it does the function body for all items at once that is weird, since timeout should work for each call of this function, why not?

Comment: I guess I have some flaw in my understanding of this function. So what it does. it will record the first call and if... 500ms pass it will do what? Just display all the elements at once without the pause?

Comment: @Andriy Ivanchenko Your function displays all images at once because this is how setTimeout functions. `setTimeout(() => (alert("Hello")), 5000)` will alert "Hello" once after 5 seconds have passed. Whatever callback you have inside set timeout will execute once after the specified time. Nested Timeout can solve your problem here. Nested Timeouts are more accurate than setInterval. Take this example, `let timerId = setTimeout ( function tick(){ alert("Hello World"); timerId = setTimeout(tick, 2000);}, 2000);`, it will alert "Hello World" after every 2 seconds.